# My mae function is different than sklearn's by a factor of 10^-16. Why?

Tags: regression

```
def mae(y_true, y_pred):

   return np.mean(abs(np.subtract(y_true, y_pred)))

my_mae_score = mae(y_train, y_pred)[0]
```

#had to do the [0] bc Series type, 1 datum point...np.float64

=0.1946780524972755443968708

```
sklearn_mae = mean_absolute_error(y_train, y_pred)
```

=0.1946780524972751835743878

Comment: sklearn_mae == my_mae_score....False

Comment: It is because you have `abs()` , it rounds off floating numbers to 10^-15 by default by my experience.

Comment: now mae is '''np.mean(np.absolute(np.subtract(y_true, y_pred)))''' and still calculates to same results... it might be worth mentioning this line. idk if that's the issue, bc same inputs, but: '''y_pred = X_train.dot(theta_best)'''